# Run PostgreSQL function to db located on Linux, from Windows command line

Tags: function, postgresql, command-line, psql

I'm trying to call PostgreSQL function from windows command line. the Postgres DB located on a Linux VM. 
I can run the command line but been prompted for password. How can I work around it?

Since the DB is on different VM, I can't modify the pgpass.conf file, it doesn't exist.
any other easy way?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `psql` on Windows to run a `SELECT` query that calls the function. To prevent `psql` from prompting for a password, you can set the password in the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable.

Optionally, for something which is generally considered somewhat more secure, you could use the `pgpass` file, which on Windows is located in **%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf** and store the password in there. More details on that can be found here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: Cool. Since it appears to have solved your issue, please accept my answer.